# Is it possible to HyperLink the image tags in modal dialog

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images extracted from JSON file, and the tag is separate array with 2 or 3 values . 
I have a search filter where onClick it executes a function that searches through my gallery , either by image title or image tag. On image click it opens a modal dialog window where i have the Exif data of the image and the image tags displayed with a ',' separator. I need those tags in the modal dialog below the exif data , to be hyperlinked. So when use click on one oof the tags ( for example: dog) to execute a search through my gallery by tag name and to display the images that contain that tag. 
My search function is ,searching through 4 pages , as i have made pagination for all the images.

HTML:

```
<div class="searchButton">
    <input type="text" id="inputValue"  data-toggle="tooltip"  placeholder="Search by name or #tag">
    <button id="searchBtn" onclick="goToPage(0,limit)" type="button">Search</button>
</div>
<div id="imageContainer"></div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <img id="current" class="modal-content" />
    <div id="exifResult"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <span id="closeDlg" class="close">Close</span>
</div>
```

JAvascript:

```
newArray= [
    0: {location: "Photos/_DSC0150.jpg", title: "Hotel", id: "image_id_001", tag: Array(3)}
    1: {location: "Photos/_DSC0226.jpg", title: "Fruit Tree", id: "Fruit_Tree", tag: Array(2)}
    2: {location: "Photos/_DSC0442.jpg", title: "Holy Trinity Church", id: "image_id_003", tag: Array(3)}
    3: {location: "Photos/_DSC6927-Е.jpg", title: "The Moon", id: "image_id_004", tag: Array(2)}
    4: {location: "Photos/_DSC7679.jpg", title: "Sunset over a lake", id: "image_id_005", tag: Array(3)}
    ]

function renderImages(data) {
let imageContainer = $('#imageContainer');
    let images= "";
    data.forEach(function (item) {
        images += (`<div class='imgBox'><img id=${item.id} src=${item.location} /><p>${item.title}</p></div>`);
    });

imageContainer.html(images);

function goToPage(pageNum, count) {

    let filter = $("#inputValue").val().toLowerCase();
    let imgIndex = pageNum * count;
    goToItem(filter,imgIndex, count);

}

let images = $(".imgBox img");
        images.click(function() {
            let currentImageTag = $(this).attr('data-category');
            modalContent.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
```

Comment: What does "tag" looks like?

Comment: tag= ["building" , "city" ,"hotel" ];

Comment: well... can't you just do the same thing as what you did on the images?

Comment: I can do it by adding `data-atribute= ${item.tag}` on the appending in `data.forEach` , but i was told there is a  better way , but i need to find it. Although even if i add the `data-atribute` and after that on click of the image i am taking the atribute and place it in the Exif data , how can i make every tag to be hyperlink ?

Comment: Add another for loop inside the foreach for tags then assign it on a variable like what you do with an image?

Comment: Can you show me some code for the `for` loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id of the image on click, and then find the array element with that id so that you can access the tags.

```
let images = $(".imgBox img");
images.click(function() {
    let currentImageTag = $(this).attr('data-category');
    modalContent.attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));

    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    let foundImgObj = newArray.find(imgObj => imgObj.id === id);
    //Do Something with foundImgObj.tag
});
```

Comment: thank you , i have done it . Can you advise how to add a hyperlink to every tag now?